# Is it possible to automatically send SMS from a webpage, if my website visitors agrees?

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to build a web based app.  when a user makes a choice to purchase a particular product, I would like to receive a automatic SMS from the users phone. Unlike using.
 Send SMS

Which still requires user to send  the SMS manually. Is there any other way around?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to register your javascript callback in your webview then after when callBack will fire the event you need to do code for send SMS programmatically
[For How to register callback with webpage in webview android](https://medium.com/@elye.project/making-android-interacting-with-web-app-921be14f99d8)

In Callback call bellow method to send sms

```
 public void sendSmsProgramatically(String phoneNumber, String message) {
            try {
                SmsManager mSmsManger = SmsManager.getDefault();
                mSmsManger.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: A web view is basically a android app displaying a html page. I want the SMS to be sent directly from a web browser and not from any app. It would be really helpful if you could suggest me the importance of callback here.